# Elements missing on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, css

I'm writing an online reasoning & logic test for mobile devices, and the blue header with the red timer just does not display in iOS (only currently tested without success in Safari & Chrome) nor does it work on Safari Mac OS (untested as yet on Android). The page displays as it should in Chrome & Firefox on Mac OS and Edge, IE & Chrome on W10.

The timer is key to allow the user to see how much time they have left on the quiz. The timer is currently set to 60 minutes but this will change later.

I had z index issues earlier which meant I had to 'lower' the radio buttons; I then discovered that the buttons were unusable as the header and footer elements were above them so I removed the z index (of -6 I think it was) and 'raised' the header 'to the top'.

If anyone can shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

https://jsfiddle.net/gtcxuz9L/4/

```js
// CLOCK START

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);

  return {
    'total': t,

    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);

  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);


    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

// CLOCK FINISH
```

```css
/*
PAGE STYLES START
*/

body{
    text-align: center;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;

}

h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
    color: #000;

}

h2 {
    font-size: 140%;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;

}

p {
    font-size: 100%;
}

#topline_container {
    border: 0px solid;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
#header {
   
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 76px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #29384a;
    right:0%;
    left:0%;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.main-div{
    width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px){
#header {    
    position:absolute !important;
    }
}



h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

textarea {
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

input {
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.timeClass {
  font-family:arial,verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:10pt;
  }

/*
PAGE STYLES END
*/


/*
FIXED BOTTOM START
*/

.fixed_bottom {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #34495e;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;

}

.fixed_bottom p{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color: #AAAAAA;

}

.fixed_bottom a {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*
FIXED BOTTOM END
*/


/*
RADIO BUTTON START
*/

.radio_container1{

  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0; left:0; right: 0; top:20;
  padding: 0;

}

.radio_container2{

  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0; left:0; right: 0; top:100;
  padding: 0;

}


.radio_container ul{
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


ul li{
  color: #AAAAAA;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
}

ul li input[type=radio]{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul li label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 0px 65px 25px 40px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

ul li:hover label{
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li .check{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 20px;
 z-index: 5;
 transition: border .25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

ul li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}

ul li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
 content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
 transition: background 0.25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 5px solid #c20031;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #c20031;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ label{
  color: #34495e;
}

/*
RADIO BUTTON END
*/


/*
CLOCK START
*/

#clockdiv{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;

}

#clockdiv > div{
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #c20031;
  display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d8708a;
  display: inline-block;
}

/*
CLOCK END
*/
```

```html
<div id="topline_container">

<div id="header"><div id="clockdiv"><div>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<form name="RT App">

<!--QUESTION 1 -->
<!--STYLE 1/3 - TEXT ONLY -->
<div class="radio_container1">
<h2>1. What was the day on 16th July 1978?</h2>
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" id="1" name="Q1" value="Friday"><label for="1">Friday</label><div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div></li>
<li><input type="radio" id="2" name="Q1" value="Sunday"><label for="2">Sunday</label><div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div></li>
<li><input type="radio" id="3" name="Q1" value="Wednesday"><label for="3">Tuesday</label><div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div></li>
<li><input type="radio" id="4" name="Q1" value="Monday"><label for="4">Monday</label><div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div></li>
</ul><br></div>
<div class="fixed_bottom"><p>Fixed <a href="">Bottom</a></p></div>
```

Comment: The `#topline_container` element has no height. Also you should consider changing this element's position to `fixed` instead of setting the `#header`'s position to `fixed`.

Comment: Thats really interesting and very useful, thankyou. I completely removed the #topline_container element as I wasn't particularly happy with it and it's appeared in Mac OS Safari - a little repositioning with CSS will see this right. Thankyou Titus.